# execute a mysql select query which has sql variables in php

Tags: php, mysql

i shall try to be as simple as possible for describing my problem

```
set @csum := 0;
update dmatrix          // dmatrix is my table name<br>
set cummulative = (@csum := @csum + datac)// here cummulative,datac are coloumns in mysql table<br>
order by id;
```

---

Expected result:
i'm able to execute simple queries but the above mentioned query i'm unable to execute it using php.
I dont know how to do even tried few ideas for cummulative sum. till now i have successfully executed above query in sql command line. i dont know y. 
thanks in advance mates.
i wanted to execute this query along with other select queries 
if not possible atleast onclick of button if the above query gets executed ,its ok.

Comment: This is not a query you posted above, but rather set of queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable assignments live for the lifetime of the connection, so you can set up your variable with one query, then run your update afterwards:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('hostname', 'username', 'password', 'schema');

$setVar = $mysqli->query("set @csum := 0") or die($mysqli->error);

$cumUpdate = $mysqli->query("update dmatrix  set cummulative = (@csum := @csum + datac) order by id;") or die($mysqli->error);
```

(This approach should be good for `mysql_*()` if you refactor it accordingly, but it's deprecated so you shouldn't be using that for new code.)

Comment: hi mike thanks for your reply i have tried this but encountered with this error  Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\foson\allocate.php on line 75

Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\foson\allocate.php on line 75

Comment: I've not seen your code. I've extended my answer to clarify usage. To use my snippets you'll need to use `mysqli` with the OOP approach. If you want to use`mysql_*()` you'll need to rework the code accordingly. You shouldn't be using `mysql_*()` though: see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have two queries here. Break them up into two PHP commands.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the set @csum := 0; is a query it should be executed by itself and the other part in another statement